# When we encounter error.recognition for a sub dialog then the next sub dialog which is generated does not have return parameters

Tags: vxml, ccxml

We are using Call Router and Call Steering java applications .
In which call Router is used to generate vxml page containing subdialog tag and Call steering is used to generate vxml page congaing return params.

In normal execution we have a Call Router subdialog as mention below.

```
<subdialog name="subdialogSubmit"
method="post"
src=https://xxxxx:xxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxx/CallSteering/xxxxx05818
namelist="CallID postbackURL handoffTarget DNIS ContextID SubdialogEvent subdialogURL SubdialogName subdialogName NOVA " >
<filled>
<assign name="SubdialogResult" expr="JSON.stringify(subdialogSubmit)" />
<goto next="#processSubdialogSuccess"/>
</filled>
<catch event="connection.disconnect.hangup">
<log>[<value expr='ContextID'/>] Caught hangup event from URL [https://xxx:xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/CallSteering/xxxxx05818] for subdi
alog [ivrcs]</log>
<assign name="SubdialogResult" expr="JSON.stringify(subdialogSubmit)" />
<assign name="SubdialogEvent" expr="_event"/>
<goto next="#processSubdialogReturn"/>
</catch>
</subdialog>
```

And once Call steering app is done it make vxml as below.

```
<form id="subdialogReturn">
<block>
<log>Returning from subdialog with parameters [IVR_Source Has_DTV CallID SubMarket DNIS Has_IPDSL Mdn ContextID CustType Has_HSIA Has_Wireless
Has_IPTV Has_DirectTV_legacy SubdialogErrorDescription Has_CVOIP Market Outcome State Region ANI ]</log>
<return namelist="IVR_Source Has_DTV CallID SubMarket DNIS Has_IPDSL Mdn ContextID CustType Has_HSIA Has_Wireless Has_IPTV Has_DirectTV_legacy
SubdialogErrorDescription Has_CVOIP Market Outcome State Region ANI " />
</block>
<catch event="connection.disconnect.hangup">
<log>Caught hangup event while returning from subdialog</log>
<var name="Outcome" expr="'HANGUP'"/>
***<return namelist="IVR_Source Has_DTV CallID SubMarket DNIS Has_IPDSL Mdn ContextID CustType Has_HSIA Has_Wireless Has_IPTV Has_DirectTV_legacy
SubdialogErrorDescription Has_CVOIP Market Outcome State Region ANI "*** />
</catch>
```

hear we got return param.
But when we get error.recognition then the next subdialog does not return any return param.
I am unable to find why this behaviour is happening.